# Name a id of Doc in FireStore || React native expo

Tags: react-native

I am using Firestore to store and retrieve messages for my chat app. Firestore collection name is "chats". Each time when I send a new message, a new Doc is created with auto generated id.

Is there any possibility of naming an id while creating in React native?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are using Firestore's `<collection-ref>.add()` method, which adds a document to a collection with an automatically generated ID.

In order to specify the ID of a document, you need to use the `<document-ref>.set()` method instead. As in the [Firestore docs example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

```js
// Web version 8
db.collection("cities").doc("new-city-id").set(data);

// Web version 9
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "new-city-id"), data);
```

Here, `"new-city-id"` can be any string, and a document with that string as an ID will be created under the `"cities"` collection.

But beware! If you don't make your document ID's unique enough, you might wind up updating an existing document, rather than creating a new one.